# Creating 6x6 matrix using bmatrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I'm trying to make a 6x6 matrix with the following text:

```
\begin{gather}
\dfrac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
    y \\ \dot{y} \\ a_{M} \\ \lambda_{T} \\ \lambda_{D} \\ a_{T}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
    0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
    0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
    0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
    0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
    0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
```

And I get the following error:

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \endtemplace \end{gather}.

Whats weird is when i check the same code for 5x5 it worked.

Thank you.

Comment: You are not making a 6x6 matrix, but rather a 11x11 matrix because of the `&&` either use `&` instead of `&&` or set the `MaxMatrixCols` counter to something higher (default i 10).

Comment: changed && to & and it worked, thank you. still cant understand why for 10x10 then it worked.

Comment: Because it was  within the bound of 10 columns. You simply had 5 empty columns alternating with columns with a digit.

Comment: you can increase the limit from 10 if you need it but you do not need it here. Also, use equation not gather for a one-line equation

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that only up to ten columns are supported by default in `matrix`-like constructions, but the number can be increased with

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
```

(twenty columns should be sufficient).

However, if you want to have wider separation between columns, set it properly, not by adding dummy columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
    y \\ \dot{y} \\ a_{M} \\ \lambda_{T} \\ \lambda_{D} \\ a_{T}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2\arraycolsep}% this change is local
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{bmatrix}
    y \\ \dot{y} \\ a_{M} \\ \lambda_{T} \\ \lambda_{D} \\ a_{T}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I'd much prefer the latter.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The input here is actually not a 6x6 matrix, but rather a 6x11 matrix (number og `&` +1. Basically you have a lot of blank columns because of the `&&`.

By default `bmatrix` and similar envs has a max of 10 columns (controlled by the counter `MaxMatrixCols`). So you get the error as there are more columns than the matrix env is defined with.

Easy solution replace `&&` by `&`.

5x5 matrix in the manner you wrote here, is the same as a 10x5 so that is within the 10 col limit.

As David mentions in a comment, use `equation(*)` for one liners, it has a build in space saving feature that the other envs does not have.

Comment: Just to be nit-picky `;-)`: the OP is making a 6x11 matrix, not 11x11.